# Where will jquery be stored?

Tags: jquery

I'm planning to use jquery frequently in my web pages. If my knowledge is correct , the file size of jquery is roughly 200K.Does the size imply that 200K bytes are downloaded for each my web page?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you use the minified/Gzipped version of jQuery its about 30KB. Always use the minified version in production code. It will get cached anyway, but the first download will be smaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; if each of your pages links to jQuery using the same URL, it'll be downloaded just once, and the browser will reuse the cached copy.

Note that many web sites link directly to the published copy of jQuery at Google; saves everybody bandwidth, as the browser can then share one copy across multiple sites! The URL is, e.g., https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js .

Comment: It's worth noting that you can get the most recent build of V1.2 by going to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2/jquery.min.js or the most recent build of V1 by going to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js . However, these are not cached, so defeat the object for the OP at least.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the URL for the jQuery script is the same, the browser will most likely cache it. Only on the first time the script is required will it be downloaded. Using a CDN may help here as it dramatically increases the likelihood of the browser already having the file cached.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery works like any other javascript link in your HTML.

The file will be downloaded into the users temporary files so that it can be read.

However depending on the browser it will be cached so that it doesn't need to be downloaded for each web page request.

As James has stated in the question comments, use the minified version of jQuery for your production version. This will reduce the initial download size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the minified version that has 92kb. (this is the last one http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

Not really, keeping javascripts in external files makes browser cache the files. So the first time the user is visiting your webpage the file will be downloaded to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yes, probably not :).

That depends on client browser configuration, if he has cache activated then the request will check if jquery in on cache and if not it will download the file and put it on cache. If cache is not activated then, yes, it will be downloaded in every page that uses it.